# cep - campos desabilitados para usuario

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5

Estou com seguinte problema: O usuário completará o CEP e irá clicar em 'buscar cep'.
Será feita uma busca do cep, e os dados serão colocados nos campos: logradouro, bairro, etc., automaticamente.

Acontece que não quero que o usuário altere essa informação que foi gerada automaticamente.
Já tente `readonly` e não obtive sucesso, porque os campos já aparecem como inativo.

Gostaria de saber se há um jeito de fazer esse tipo de tratamento.

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="logradouro">Logradouro</label>  
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input id="logradouro" name="logradouro" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="required" type="text" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem de ser um input? porque não colocar isso numa div?

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Há casos em que o CEP não possui o endereço, quando for cidade pequena, então o usuário terá que digitar o endereço, sugiro validar essa necessidade em sua aplicação.

Comment: Joga os dados do logradouro em uma div, caso vocÊ queira enviar esses dados para o server, coloca na div e em um campo hidden.

Comment: coloquei o inpu html na pergunta.

Comment: no retorno da sua função se for diferente de null, você desabilita os campos.

Comment: mostre sua função que busca o cep

Comment: Se você colocar isso de forma a não se alterar, vai ter problemas. A base de CEP está cheia de coisas com problema. Inclusive, o meu CEP mesmo mostra uma rua que não é a minha nos grandes sites que usam a base paga dos correios. Como o @PedroCamaraJunior disse, preveja a necessidade de editar.

Comment: Muito bem observado pelo @Bacco. Eu tenho essa função em meu sistema, mas deixo sempre habilitado para edição.

Comment: então durtto, seria isso que eu queria, a pessoa digita o cep, clica no botão buscarcep e automaticamente aparece nos campos as informações. no seu caso aparece inativo as informações e o usuário tem o botão alterar cep?

Answer (score 2):

> Basta utilizar a propiedade **disabled**.

```
    <input id="numero" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
    <input id="cidade" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
    <input id="logradouro" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 1):

O que vc quer é um disabled no input. Saca só esse exemplo:

```
 <form action="action.html">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

O input "last name" está desativado e não pode ser alterado.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo as respostas anteriores, você só precisa adicionar um método `disabled` para a tag `input`, mas por recomendação, caso a informação gerada não seja correta, seria interessante que o usuário pudesse corrigir os campos (Principalmente se for um campo `Required`).

**Solução em `HTML`:**

```
<input id="logradouro" name="logradouro" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="required" type="text" disabled>
```

Você também pode criar uma solução em CSS como a que eu vou deixar aqui abaixo, mas você precisará só adicionar uma cor diferente ao `input` (um cinza escuro qualquer).

**Solução em `CSS`:**

```
#logradouro{
   pointer-events: none;
   tab-index: -1;
}
```

Caso você queira uma última solução, um `jQuery` pode te servir, mas ainda assim seria mais fácil a solução em `HTML` mesmo. A vantagem do `jQuery` nesse caso é que, se o usuário não informar o CEP e em contra partida quiser preencher manualmente, você pode remover a propriedade do `disabled` do `input`, deixando-a ativa somente se ele preencher o campo CEP e selecionar preenchimento automático.

**Solução em `jQuery`:**

```
$('#logradouro').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Adiciona a propriedade disabled.
$('#logradouro').removeAttr('disabled'); //Remove a propriedade disabled.
```

UPDATE DO JQUERY

Na hora de responder e criar o código, acabei ficando um pouco na dúvida se o método `attr` ainda era o certo a ser usado, mas vi que não pode servir muito bem. Um método melhor seria o `prop`.

```
$('#logradouro').prop('disabled', true); //Adiciona a propriedade
$('#logradouro').prop('disabled', false); //Remove a propriedade
```